# Combinatorics problem involving n-dimensional space

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

Consider a set of more than $\frac {2^{n+1}} {n}$ points $(n>2)$, chosen from the $2^n$ points of the $n$-dimensional space which have the coordinates $\{ \pm1, \pm1, ..., \pm1 \}$.

Show that there are $3$ points in the set that form an equilateral triangle.
I don't know how to start, as I am new in combinatorics problems.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the pigeonhole principle (which the problem formulation clearly suggests to do), one can show that moreover there is an equilateral triangle with the side equal to $2\sqrt{2}$.

Consider the set $V$ of points of the form $\{\pm 1,\dots, \pm 1\}$ (these are vertices of an $n$-hypercube). Call two of them *neighbors* if they differ in exactly one coordinate (in other words, they are connected by an edge). Note that the distance between any two different points from $V$ with a common neighbor is $2\sqrt{2}$.

Now each of the chosen points has $n$ neighbors. So in total there are more than $2^{n+1}$ neighbors to the chosen points. Since there are $2^n$ points in $V$, by the pigeonhole principle, some element of $V$ is a neighbor to at least three of the chosen points. By the above remark, these three points form the desired equilateral triangle.